# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null I get this error for every time I try to use textContent, innerText

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error for every time I try to use textContent, innerText. For example:

```
  //Javascript
let OtpCodeEl = document.getElementById("otpcode")
console.log(OtpCodeEl)

  function genOtpCode() {
    let otpCode = Math.floor(Math.random()*111111111)
    console.log(otpCode)
    setTimeout(clearOtp(), 60000)
    OtpCodeEl.textContent = otpCode
    console.log(OtpCodeEl)
  }

  function clearOtp() {
    otpcode = 0
  }
```

```
<!--html-->
<html>
    <body>
            <!-- Sources-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylerTwo.css">
            <script src= "mainer.js" ></script>
    
        <h1 id="title">OTP CODE</h1>
        <h4 class="text">Open the File Cabinet app on your phone and click on <br>
            scan receipt, then click on generate code below. Finally, <br>
            enter the code into the app and scan the receipt.
        </h4>
        <img id="iphoneImg" src="phone.jpeg">
        <button id="genCode" onclick="genOtpCode()" >Generate Code</button>
        <h4 class="text" id="otpcode"></h4>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried innerText for OtpCodeEl but it still shows the same error

Comment: Move "<script src= "mainer.js" ></script>" to last line in body part.

Comment: Alternatively to loading your JS file at the end of your file, you could also make use of jQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { /* Code goes here */ });`. There are pure JS solutions to get the same effect (there are even lightweight libraries that offer just the document.ready functionality, and nothing more).

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the mainer.js file at the bottom of your html file (right before the closing tag of the body). It is the matter of the order code.
Another workaround is to add defer attribute to the script. eg:

```html
<script src="mainer.js" defer></script>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  ... anything
  </head>
 
  <body>
  ...
    <script src="mainer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```